# How can I solve TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument error

Tags: python, arrays, class, object, typeerror

I check similar questions and answers here but I can't see the missing piece in my code. With this code

```
class Solution:
    def __init__(self,arr):
        self.arr = arr
        
    def minDeletionSize(self):
        cnt = 0
        for n,c in enumerate(self.arr):
            sortedAsc = "".join(sorted(c))           
            sortedDesc = ''.join(reversed(sortedAsc))

            if (c != sortedAsc and c != sortedDesc):
                cnt += 1
                
        print(cnt)
    
if __name__ == '__main__':

     arrays = [["cba","daf","ghi"],["a","b"],["zyx","wvu","tsr"]]
     for arr in arrays:
         obj = Solution(arr)
         obj.minDeletionSize()
```

I got this error message

```
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'arr'
ret = Solution().minDeletionSize(param_1)
Line 43 in _driver (Solution.py)
    _driver()
Line 54 in <module> (Solution.py)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This line: `ret = Solution().minDeletionSize(param_1)` is not in the posted code. Where is it?

Comment: that's all your code? what lines is 43? it's seems that the problem is that somewhere you are instantiating the `Solution` class but without initialisation param `Solution().minDeletionSize(param_1)` so it does not have initialized self.arr. If `_driver` is a method of  `Solution` then you can use : `self.minDeletioSize(param_1)`

Comment: I'm also confused too. That's all in terms of code. I compile it on leetcode. can that be a problem on their side?

Comment: It looks like `arr` is supposed to be a parameter of `minDeletionSize`, not a constructor parameter.

Comment: The error message references a line in the code that *uses* the `Solution` class you provide. You need to write `Solution` according to the interface expected by that code.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica if you mean doing this `def minDeletionSize(self,arr):`, it doesn't work either.